# Integrating Branch.io with Google Analytics when app is connected using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, branch.io

I want to integrate Branch.io with the Google Analytics property for my app.

I have succesfully linked my app to Google Analytics using Firebase, but since I used Firebase as the tracking method, I don't have any Tracking ID, that I can enter in Branch.io's data integrations.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not have direct integration with Firebase. You can switch to Google Analytics to obtain your tracking ID. You can find more info on our [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/integrations/google-analytics/#search).